# How to insert into select with different number of column?

Tags: java, oracle

I have a task to move a data from `X` table `SCHEMA_A` to `SCHEMA_B`.

The problem is that table `SCHEMA_A.X` has 4 columns (`sid`, `is_deleted`, `c`, `d`) and table `SCHEMA_B.X` has 5 columns (`sid`, `is_deleted`, `rid`, `c`, `d`).

How can I insert value for column rid from another table where in this case I want to make the query as dynamic as possible?
Currently I can only think of modifying this query somehow

```sql
INSERT INTO SCHEMA_B.X
SELECT * FROM SCHEMA_A.X Aa
WHERE A.is_deleted = 'n'
```

Thank you before

Answer (score 2):

add a dummy column

```
insert into SCHEMA_B.X
select *, 0 as  dummy_columm
from SCHEMA_A.X Aa
WHERE A.is_deleted = 'n'
```

You can use `NULL` or another special value to indicate his origin

Comment: Wouldn't it insert `c` from `SCHEMA_A` in `rid` column of `SCHEMA_B` and so on?

Comment: well instead of *, put each field name, and put the dummy column name it as the column you dont have in schema A

Comment: Yes. That's what I gave in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way

```
insert into SCHEMA_B.X (sid,is_deleted,rid,c,d)
select sid,is_deleted,0 as rid,c,d 
from SCHEMA_A.X A
WHERE A.is_deleted = 'n'
```

Comment: hmm i i'm gonna use the query for many tables, if i list the columns, it won't be dynamic, i generate the table name and put it in loop, that's why i don't put each field name, thanks before

Comment: but without this you risk wrong columns to be mapped.

Comment: You can create stored procedure and in it, you get column list from both the tables, see the difference, fill it in correct order and save the statement in variable. And then you can execute immediate it.

Comment: stored procedure?hmm i never used that before, thank's i'll learn about it